# spinner setOnItemClickListener is crash?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

```
    holder.spinner_teacher_name=(Spinner) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_teacher_name);

    holder.spinner_teacher_name=(Spinner) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_teacher_name);

    arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(rowView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,teacher_name);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    holder.spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), "You Clicked "+class_room[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be used selected listener, not click listener

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
            {
             String selected_item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
             Log.d("TAG", "_log : item_selected : " + selected_item);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
            {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Sir kindly i want to know some detail about this line

Comment: Log.d("TAG", "_log : item_selected : " + selected_item);

Comment: It'll print the item that You select from the spinner ;)

Comment: @Muhammad Idrees : You marked this solution as the accepted answer. But today You ignore it as the accepted answer. May I know what's the reason?

Comment: wasn't it solve ur crashing issue that u mention ur question? if ur app crashes for further functionality, that's another issue.

Comment: yes sir . you right . it si not crashing but not solve .anyway i marked it again. i just want to get selected item on spinner . when i run application it is already selected item . i need after dropdown spinner on selected item ... not befor selected item...

Answer (score 0):

When the user `selects` an item from the `drop-down`, the `Spinner` object receives an `on-item-selected` event.

To define the `selection` event handler for a `spinner`, implement the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` interface and the corresponding `onItemSelected()` callback method.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener).

**Use:**

```
holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), "You Clicked " + class_room[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```

**Instead of:**

```
holder.spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), "You Clicked "+class_room[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```